# How can i write single condition for multiple statements in AWS IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add condition for policy expiration :

```
"Condition": {
    "DateGreaterThan": {
        "aws:CurrentTime": "2020-01-22T12:29:59Z"
    },
    "DateLessThan": {
        "aws:CurrentTime": "2020-11-22T19:35:00Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't want to add condition in all statement blocks because there are so many blocks in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I didn't test it):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "s3:*"
            ]
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "DateGreaterThan": {
                    "aws:CurrentTime": "2020-01-22T12:29:59Z"
                },
                "DateLessThan": {
                    "aws:CurrentTime": "2020-11-22T19:35:00Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It will work but in my case there are so many statement blocks with different "Resource" and "Condition". So i can't integrate all the "Action" in one.